# Verses indicating that each person has an equal entitlement to a land-plot

Tags: sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, pentateuch-chumash, real-estate, estates-inheritance

In [Numbers 26:53–54](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0426.htm#53) (JPS), the Israelites are commanded:

> Unto these the land shall be divided for an inheritance according to the number of names. To the more thou shalt give the more inheritance, and to the fewer thou shalt give the less inheritance; to each one according to those that were numbered of it shall its inheritance be given.

This seems to imply that each person should get an equal land-plot. I.e., if tribe A has 1000 people and tribe B has 500 people, then tribe A should get a land that is twice as big as tribe B, so that finally each person from each tribe gets an equal land-plot.

The Jubilee commandment in [Leviticus 25:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0325.htm#10), "ye shall return every man unto his possession, and ye shall return every man unto his family" (JPS), also seems to indicate that each person has a right to own a land (though not necessarily equal to the lands of others).

My question is: are there verses that express this requirement in a more direct and explicit manner?

I am looking both for commandment verses and for ideological verses, i.e., verses that say that each person has, in principle, an equal right to a land-plot.

I prefer a verse from the Bible, but other sources are of course always welcome

Comment: I prefer a verse from the Bible, but other sources are of course always welcome :)

Comment: Talmud, bava batra from about 118 to 123 treats a related passage at great length, you might want to start research there.